# Format code in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have typed code in Java for Android in Eclipse. The formatting is not nice. Is there any way I can automatically format it using keyboard shortcuts?
Any help will be highly regarded...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press ***[Ctrl]+[Shift]+F***  to auto format the java code in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Use Ctrl + Shift +F to auto format the code

Answer (score 1):

For Formatting code in eclipce press `ctrl+shift+f`

Answer (score 1):

Press ctrl + A and then ctrl + I and as well as you can press ctrl+ shift+ F for formatting code in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

//Right click your project and select

```
Source -> Format
```

this will format your whole project

same way if your do organize your imports it will good.

`Source -> Organize Imports [Ctrl+ Shift +o]`

Answer (score 0):

Press `ctrl + A` and then `ctrl + I` and as well as you can press `ctrl+ shift+ F` for formatting code in Eclipse.

Comment: ctrl + A is not necessary .

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl+I it will align automatically...

Answer (score 0):

You should really have a look at

Eclipse in that Window > Preferences > Keys .
You can find all of the shortcuts there and you can also define you own shortcuts you want. 
And you can also set you formatter to custom format the you want to format your code in 
Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style. 
And AS YOU KNOW.  
ctrl + shift + f is the autoformat shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Just press : Ctrl + Shift + F

Hope this helps.